# How to check if MQ is connected

Tags: ibm-mq

I'm trying to connect to my MQ servers. I have 2 MQ Server: server 1 and server 2 and set it as `connectionNameList` for `mqConnectionFactory`. Is there a way for MQ to connect to server 1 if server 2 failed? How can I know if MQ server is connected? I saw that there is `clientReconnectOptions` set to `67108864` but I'm not sure what is that.

Comment: Yes it’s on java

Comment: Hi it’s the ibm mq class for jms

Comment: Can you post an example of what you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possible settings for ClientReconnectOptions are documented in the IBM MQ Knowledge center page [CLIENTRECONNECTOPTIONS](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q111980_.htm)

Below is an example using `setClientReconnectOptions` to set it so the application can reconnect to any queue manager listing on the two host(port) combinations set in the `connectionNameList`.

```
MQQueueConnectionFactory factory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();

factory.setQueueManager("QMNAME");
factory.setChannel("SVRCONN.CHL");
factory.setConnectionNameList("hostName1(port),hostName2(port)");
factory.setClientReconnectOptions( WMQConstants.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT );

// Set the amount of time you will attempt to reconnect in seconds
factory.setClientReconnectTimeout( 43200 ); //12 hours
//default is 1800 seconds
//factory.setClientReconnectTimeout(WMQConstants.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT);
```

Note that clients will not always attempt to reconnect, see the following from the `endmqm` man page on Linux:

> If you issue endmqm to stop a queue manager, reconnectable clients do
>   not try to reconnect. To override this behavior, specify either the -r
>   or -s option to enable clients to start trying to reconnect.
>
> Note: If a queue manager or a channel ends unexpectedly, reconnectable
>   clients start trying to reconnect.

Comment: Thanks i got it working by setup the clientreconnectionTimeOut

Comment: Glad to help, thank you for the accept.   What value did you go with?

Comment: Hi I went with these 2 options and it works ClientReconnectOptions = 67108864 and ClientReconnectTimeout = WMQConstants.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT

Comment: Note that the default is 1800 seconds (30 minutes).  This means that if both of your server 1 and server 2 are both down for any extended maintenance it will give up after 30 minutes and a restart of the app will be required.

Comment: sorry but If I have 2 connection servers in setConnectionNameList. How can I know if hostName1 or hostName2 get connected?

Comment: @RLe I researched and didn't find any documented way to do this.  I tried a test and `getHostName` always returned the first host in the `ConnectionNameList` no matter if it failed to connect to the first host and was actually connected to the second host.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for helping. I couldn’t find it also. I will let u know if I found out